# Почему dropdown меню появляется только 1 раз?

Tags: css

При первом наведении выпадание срабатывает, после необходимо перезагрузить страницу, чтобы оно опять выпало при наведении[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.navigation-item {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 2%;
   padding: 10px 0;}
.dropdown > .dropdown-link::after {
    content: "";
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #CCC;}

  .dropdown .dropdown-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;}

  .dropdown .dropdown-link {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #F5F5F7;
    font-size: 18px;}

  .dropdown-item-link {
    color: #F5F5F7;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 0.8;}

  .dropdown-item-link:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;}

  .dropdown-item-link:not(:hover) {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;}

  .dropdown .dropdown-item {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 500ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;}

  .dropdown.hover:hover .dropdown-item{
    height: 40px;}

  .dropdown.hover:hover .dropdown-item:first-child {
    padding-top: 15px;}
```

Comment: [mcve] в виде сниппета добавь в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все прекрасно работает, просто у тебя дочерние элементы выходили за пределы родитетя, а ты курсор не достаточно отводил.  вот тебе твой пример  с добавленныим background

hover наследуется

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.dropdown>.dropdown-link::after {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #CCC;
  background: #000;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #444;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #F5F5F7;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #252525;
}

.dropdown-item-link {
  color: #F5F5F7;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: #0f0f0f;
}

.dropdown-item-link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown-item-link:not(:hover) {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-item {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 500ms;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.dropdown.hover:hover .dropdown-item {
  height: 40px;
}

.dropdown.hover:hover .dropdown-item:first-child {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<li class="navigation-item dropdown hover"><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">zina0</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item-link">zina1</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item-link">zina2</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item-link">zina3</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item-link">zina4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```